# How can I count the number of sentences in a given text in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, count, sentence

I wanted to create a playground that would count the number of sentences of a given text.

```
let input = "That would be the text . it hast 3. periods. "

func sentencecount() {
    let periods = CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.union(.punctuationCharacters)
    let periods = input.components(separatedBy: spaces)
    let periods2  = Int (words.count)
    print ("The Average Sentence length is \(periods2)") 
}
sentencecount()
```

Comment: Dear Matt I will edit my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the character in `charset` by which you are going to differentiate your sentences:

**I am assuming `? . ,` for now:**

```
    let input = "That would be the text. it hast 3? periods."
    let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".?,")
    let arr = input.components(separatedBy: charset)
    let count = arr.count - 1
```

Here `arr` would be:

```
["That would be the text", " it hast 3", " periods", ""]
```

decrease count by 1, to get actual sentences.

**Note:** If you don't want to consider `" , "` then remove it from `charset`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ankit . Here the final solution I got thanks to you :

Comment: func sentencecount ()->Double {
    
 
    let input = "That would be the text. it hast 3? periods."
    let charset = CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".?,")
    let arr = input.components(separatedBy: charset)
    let arrcount = Double (arr.count)
    let doubleone:Double = 1
    let count:Double = arrcount - doubleone
    
    print ("The Average Sentence length is ", countofwords/count, "Words ")
    
    return(count)
}

Comment: @Valentin, welcome :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumerateSubstrings(in: Range)` and use option `.bySentences`:

```
let input = "Hello World !!! That would be the text. It hast 3 periods."
var sentences: [String] = []
input.enumerateSubstrings(in: input.startIndex..., options: .bySentences) { (string, range, enclosingRamge, stop) in
    sentences.append(string!)
}
```

An alternative is to use an array of Substrings instead of Strings:

```
var sentences: [Substring] = []
input.enumerateSubstrings(in: input.startIndex..., options: .bySentences) { (string, range, enclosingRamge, stop) in
    sentences.append(input[range])
}
```

---

```
print(sentences)   // "["Hello World !!! ", "That would be the text. ", "It hast 3 periods."]\n"
print(sentences.count)  // "3\n"
```

Comment: I was waiting for this :) – Note that you can specify the range as as “one-sided range” `in: input.startIndex...`, compare https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0172-one-sided-ranges.md

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
   let input = "That would be the text . it hast 3. periods. "
   let occurrencies = input.characters.filter { $0 == "." || $0 == "?" }.count
   print(occurrencies)
   //result 3
```

Comment: Thanks I will check ;)

Comment: It says : Playground execution failed:

error: textcoach.playground:76:30: error: ambiguous use of 'filter'
    let occurrencies = input.characters.filter{ $0 == "." || $0 == "?" }.count

Comment: which version of swift do you have ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see that you need to split them using . and trimming whitespaces as the following:

```
func sentencecount () {

    let result = input.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces).split(separator: ".")

   print ("The Average Sentence length is \(result.count)") // 3
}
```

Good luck!